# Python: Delete locked file

Tags: python

How do I delete a file with Python (Windows) that has a read lock?

The obvious, doesn't work:

```
  import os
  os.remove("test_file.csv")
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
   WindowsError: [Error 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being
   used by another process: 'test_file.csv'
```

Comment: What has the file handle? Your script? Or another program?

Comment: You need to close the program that has that file opened.

Comment: In the Win32 API, there is a way to open a file such that it will get deleted when the program closes. I don't know if that's exposed in Python somewhere.

However, maybe you're doing this for a temporary file that you open yourself? In that case, check out the `tempfile` module.

Comment: Windows doesn't allow you to delete a open file. You can only schedule its deletion.

Comment: For a Linux version see: [Detect and delete locked file in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1320812/detect-and-delete-locked-file-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to **unconditionally** force the closure of the active handle so you can delete the file, you could leverage Microsoft's [*handle* tool](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655.aspx) using the file name as the argument (which will return all file handles with that string in the object name), and then the invoke *handle* again using the `-c` option specifying the exact handle to close and the pid it belongs to.

I have used this method successfully in the past in cases where I knew I wanted to absolutely, unconditionally kill the active handles on a particular file/directory so I could proceed with another action.

However, keep in mind that, as the documentation for *handle* states:

> WARNING: Closing handles can cause application or system instability.

You can use `subprocess.check_output` to invoke *handle*.

[More subprocess info](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html)